# How to run a test for some column relative to all the rest columns in R?

Tags: r

I want to do grangertest() for some column relative to all the rest columns in data frame.
How can I do this automatically ?

```
library(lmtest)

df <- data.frame(rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100))

grangertest(df[, 1] ~ df[, 2], order = 1)
grangertest(df[, 1] ~ df[, 3], order = 1)
grangertest(df[, 1] ~ df[, 4], order = 1)
grangertest(df[, 1] ~ df[, 5], order = 1)

grangertest(df[, 2] ~ df[,1], order = 1)
grangertest(df[, 2] ~ df[,3], order = 1)
grangertest(df[, 2] ~ df[,4], order = 1)
grangertest(df[, 2] ~ df[,5], order = 1)

# and so on, with different values of "order"
```

As a result, I want to get a table with values `F` and `Pr(>F)` for each combination of variables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also go for lapply.

```
library(lmtest)

df <- data.frame(rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100),
                 rnorm(100))


lapply(df[,-1], grangertest, df[,1])
lapply(df[,-2], grangertest, df[,2])
lapply(df[,-3], grangertest, df[,3])
lapply(df[,-4], grangertest, df[,4])
```

`lapply()` applies a function to a list (here the dataframe is a list of vectors) and returns a list that contains the results.

Answer (score 0):

Please revise your question to be a good question and contain a reproducible example.

Either way, regarding your question:
What you want to do is apply a function to all the columns in the dataframe. Here's the dplyr solution:

```
library(tidyverse) # load the package(s) you need (the dplyr package is contained here)

df <- mtcars # I'll just take one of the in-built R datasets

compareVar <- df$mpg # I copy one variable of the dataframe

df %>% # I take the dataframe
    select(-mpg) %>% # remove the variable I copied before
    summarise_all(cor, y = compareVar) # and apply the function cor() to all columns
```

Important: you have to provide the function (`cor()` in my case `grangertest()` in your case) without the parentheses, i.e. you pass the object. Additional arguments must be provided also within the `summarise_all()` function. In my case the argument I provide is `y =` - it is an argument of the function `cor()`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Your answer is valuable, but in the case of `grangertest()` is not work. I added a reproducible example.